# VERY easy MySQL syntax error, I'm new to this

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I am trying to make an incredibly basic form that adds First name, last name, and age to a very basic database called Test. Here is my HTML code:

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<br>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname">
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname">
Age: <input type="text" name="age">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>

</body>

</html>
```

And this is my PHP code, with the DB name, host, and login info hidden:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("HOST","USER","PASS","DB");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql=   "INSERT INTO Test ('First Name', 'Last Name', 'Age')
        VALUES
        ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This is my error when I type data in to the form and submit it. I am directed to this page:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''First Name', 'Last Name', 'Age') VALUES ('Robert','Maxwell','18')' at line 1
```

Comment: Use back ticks instead of `'` to quote your column names.

Comment: I doubt you have got spaces on your field titles.

Comment: Before you do **anything** else, read up on how to [avoid SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) by [using SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php). What you're doing here is completely reckless and leaves you wide open to all kinds of severe problems. `mysqli` has the [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) method that makes it very easy to do this correctly and safely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$sql=   "INSERT INTO Test ('First Name', 'Last Name', 'Age')
```

for

```
$sql=   "INSERT INTO Test (`First Name`, `Last Name`, `Age`)
```

;-)

Comment: This is if one insists on being *that guy* and having spaces in their column names.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I'm working on my syntax.. It's horrific right now, I know.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is incorrect, you wont have spaces in your column tables - they must be camel case (FirstName) or underscore (first_name)

```
    $sql=   "INSERT INTO Test (`First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `Age`)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";
```

or

```
    $sql=   "INSERT INTO Test (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `Age`)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";
```

***NB: Do NOT use in production, your queries are exposed. Look into protecting your queries against SQL injection.***

Comment: You can actually have spaces in your column names, it's just a **really** bad idea

Comment: @phil ... I didnt know that, thanks! But like you said, a bad idea, so I wont be using it anytime soon :)

Comment: MySQL's table name delimiter is backtick, not regular tick.